# MySQL : Performance of adding new column to partitioned table vs non-partitioned table

Tags: mysql, database-performance, partitioning

I already searched quite a bit but couldn't find any info on following scenario.

Considering an InnoDB table with more than 500,000 rows, ~20 columns and INDEX on ~5 columns.

What is the performance difference of executing an "ALTER TABLE" query to add a new column on such a table, when this table is:

1. Partitioned using HASH partitioning on primary key (integer), v/s
2. Not Partitioned

Answer (score 0):

Bluntly put, `PARTITION BY HASH` provides no performance improvement.  So, don't even consider it using it.

As for your specific question, I would *guess* that non-partitioned would be faster.  Here's the logic:

A partitioned table is really a wrapper around a bunch of "sub-tables".  `ADD INDEX` would need to modify each subtable.  Although the number of rows to add the column to would total the same either way, there is extra overhead for having more "tables" to work with.

Comment: Thanks for answering! So partitioning would have same effect if I manually partition this table horizontally into multiple tables, and then add a column to each table? 
Basically my requirement is to add a lot of columns to this table without slowing down "ALTER TABLE" query to add columns, even when number of rows keep growing. Will manually partitioning such table both horizontally and vertically help? E.g restricting each table to 10,000 rows and ~50 columns?

Comment: Manually + horiz + vert ==> nightmare.  Back up...  What kind of data do you have, how often do you need to add columns, what kind of columns, etc.  See also:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav  for another way to deal with open-ended columns.

Comment: My app allows users to add custom attributes to a form. Each user has a separate table. Based on the type of attribute selected by user, the app adds related column to that user's table. So the frequency of adding columns depends on users, which is usually not too often...Kind of columns: VARCHAR, MEDIUMTEXT, TEXT, INT, FLOAT. Also users can search using any of the columns in their table, we can not limit this to specific columns, so the BLOB/JSON approach in the link you shared doesn't seem to fit this scenario.

Comment: Theoretically there being multiple sub-tables it should be possible to do the work in parallel so on a system with high resources if it is optimized in this way it should be much faster. I don't know yet if it works though..

Comment: @ColinM - InnoDB is reasonably efficient at handling multiple queries hitting the same table.  That is, splitting the data into multiple tables _just for performance reasons_ is usually not beneficial.

Comment: @RickJames I was referring to the ADD COLUMN operation specifically when it requires a table copy and thinking that copying 10 smaller tables could perhaps be faster than 1 large table if it is able to use more parallelization. I just need to test to know for sure though.

Comment: @ColinM - Alas, there is essentially zero parallelism in MySQL.

Comment: Anyway, rebuilding 10 tables is I/O-bound, and all I/O goes through one OS funnel.  If you have RAID striping, you can get some I/O parallelism, but that applies to a serial ALTER anyway.  See also [_High speed ingestion_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table)

Comment: Thanks @RickJames, great blog too, btw!